# Accept command line arguments as numbers

Tags: python

I need to accept all arguments as array.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
value = sys.argv[1:]
print value
```

when run it, I got this

```
$ python a.py 23 4 3 4
['23', '4', '3', '4']
```

What I want to get is :

```
 [23, 4, 3, 4]
```

How to do that? Thanks.

Comment: call `int()` on all elements (e.g.: using a list comprehension)

Comment: Convert each input into an `int` - `value = [int(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]]` (or just call `int(value[1])` to get the integer of a specific value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast each argument to `int`. However, it might throw exception in case argument is not parseable. Try this way:

```
import sys

args = sys.argv[1:]

parsed_args = []

for a in args:
    try:
        parsed_args.append(int(a))
    except ValueError:
        print 'Not able to parse %s to int' % a

print parsed_args
```

This way you handle arguments in case those are not parseable and you get stable runtime.